# Hyperx Cloud Revolver vs HyperX Cloud Revolver S

Tags: audio, headset

So, on hyperX website they claim the HyperX Cloud Revolver S has an 7.1 sound, and say that the regular Cloud Revolver does not have it.

But if it is not 7.1 is it 5.1? I ask that, because I heard that 5.1 headsets cannot connect with PS4 for instance.

But the regular HyperX Cloud Revolver, does connect to PS4, so i'm kind of confused.

www.hyperxgaming.com/us/headsets/cloud-revolver-gaming-headset

Thanks

ps: I was recommended to move my question from https://hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com to here

Comment: It could just be, you know... Stereo *gasp*

Comment: and what that means in comparisson to 7.1? noob here